# Make mobile friendly html form

Tags: html, css

I have an buy and sell forms with price etc.. It looks perfect in laptop but as I try to see it through my iphone, I only see sell button and three input areas. Here is my Css:-

```
#ordersell {
background-color: #a82226;
}

.orderbutton {
text-align: center;
display: flex;
color: #fff;
margin: 0 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 700;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 3px;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
 border-style: groove;
 padding: 10px;

}

.input101 {
font-family: Poppins-Medium;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 1;
color: #666666;
display: block;
width: 75px;
background: #e6e6e6;
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid #666;
}

label {
display: block;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
color: #09cdf9;
}

#orderbuy {
background-color: #22a826;
}
```

And this is my HTML code:-

```
<div style="display: flex;">
<form method="post" action="usdbtc.php" class="login100-form validate-form" style="width: 500px; height:160px; float:left;">    
<p>
<label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: left;" type="text" name="username" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
<label style="float: right;">: BTC</label>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box2" oninput="calculate()"><br>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="result"><br>
<label style="padding: 10px;">Total BTC:</label>
<td rowspan="2"><br>
<span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="ordersell">SELL</span>
</p>
</td>
</form>
<form method="post" action="usdbtc.php" class="login100-form validate-form" style="width: 500px; height:160px; float:right;">
<p>
<label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: left;" type="text" name="username" id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
<label style="float: right;">: BTC</label>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="box4" oninput="calculate()"><br>
<input class="input101" style="width: 135px; float: right;" type="text" name="username" id="resul"><br>
<label style="padding: 10px;">Total BTC:</label>
<td rowspan="2"><br>
<span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="orderbuy">BUY</span>
</p>
</td>
</form>
</div>
```

Any ideas how to show it properly in Mobile display? It appears that whenever the screen size goes below 600px , it tends to happen. Help is appreciated.

Comment: As I see it you would have to do a general rework of your HTML, because from what I can see this is tag soup (i. e. tags used in places where they aren't supposed to be used like `<td>` outside of a table row and so outside of a table, labels that aren't associated with their respective input fields, invalid nesting, et al.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@media` rules can help to make your design responsive. But looks like you are using inline css as "`style="width:50px;height:50px`"

You have to give id or class to the respective div(s) or html elements so that you can make them responsive as below:

For displays less than 600px, all you have do is add css inside `media` like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
   /* then insert your css elements  */
   .yourclass{
    width:100%;
  }
   .yourid{
  width:100%;
  }
  input[text]{
  width:100%;
  background:green;
}
/*etc*/
}
```

For Example, here's the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/s4yeof9c/
Try resizing

Hope this helps :)

```
@media only screen and (max-width:445px){
/* all css here goes for mobile .. i'm not sure about how much pixel though :D */
}

@media only screen and (max-width:800px){
/* all css here goes for tablets */
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1366px){
/* all css here goes for screens with 1366px */
}
```

and so on..

Comment: Thanks, I changed most of the height and width to % from px.. it seems to work but I dont see the text which was suppossed to be next to input in <label> tags

Comment: Hi, it's all about css. You have to align and divide space for your label and input elements so that everything is visible. Please update your code so that we can solve more :) Thanks

Comment: [Picture](https://pasteboard.co/HC2kzqI.jpg) The code above renders this on laptop...How to customize on mobile...straight question :)(Only the sell and buy forms)

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand. Did you mean "for mobile view"?
You have to add multiple @media queries for different pixels. Wait, i'll update solution. See if this is what you are asking for :)

Comment: Click on the picture see it...thats what i see on laptop...how to customize it for mobile

Comment: I've updated comment, Please check if this is what you mean :)